# "error expected expression before '{' token"

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, definition

I'm trying to declare global extern array and define it in another file but error is given. Please find the code snippet below

**in .h**

```
extern unsigned int HoldingRegisters[2];
```

**in .c**

```
HoldingRegisters={2,0};
```

*"error expected expression before '{' token"*

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to provide a name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This record in the header file `in.h`

```
extern unsigned int HoldingRegisters[2];
```

is a declaration of an array but not its definition.

In the  file `in.c` apart from the declaration you need also to define the array like

```
unsigned int HoldingRegisters[2] = {2,0};
```

This definition must be placed in the file scope outside any function as for example

```
#include "in.h>

unsigned int HoldingRegisters[2] = {2,0};

//...
```

Otherwise this record that you shall remove)

```
HoldingRegisters={2,0};
```

represents an attempt to assign a braced list to the variable `HoldingRegisters` of the array type. However arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. That is they do not have the copy assignment operator and moreover in an assignment you need to use an expression and braced lists  are not expressions.

Comment: gives: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
   80 |  unsigned int HoldingRegisters={2,0};
      |                                                          ^

Comment: @KhaledSaleh It means that you need to reread my answer one more.

Comment: and :  error ... undefined reference to `HoldingRegisters'

Comment: What statement would you suggest I use in place of braced lists?